# Insert characters at the middle and the end of a line with specific line length

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Currently I am working on a folder of files, and each file have some lines as follows:

```
abcde    fghij
abcde    fghij
jklmn    pqrst
.....    .....
```

These lines have a specific line length 43. At the middle of each line is a tab character, and at the end is the windows line break character `^M`. I would like to do the following steps:

```
 First, select these lines with line length 43
 Second, replace the tab in the middle with a comma
 Third, replace the line break character at the end with a dot.
```

And the expected output should be like this:

```
abcde, fghij.
abcde, fghij.
jklmn, pqrst.
```

I have tried `sth` as follows, but I failed:

```
 sed -i -e 's/^.\{43\}\r/ ./g' input.file
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

**Update** You can click [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vh4jA_d7t_T1sRBSTg904vOSHayYNx4C) to get a **test file**.

Comment: So 43 is length including the tab and `^M` or excluding both?

Comment: @Inian, including both characters.

Comment: I neither find a tab character in your test file nor a line of 43 characters. Better paste your file in the question (indend each line with four spaces for fformatting), so we know we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Philippos Thank you for your help. Sorry, I used awk print to count the number of characters, but it seems 43 is not correct,. The solution of laenkeio is correct, just change the number and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
sed -ne '/^.\{43\}$/s/\t/, /g;/^.\{44\}$/s/\r/./gp' input.file > new.file
```

or if you're on mac os:

```bsh
sed -ne $'/^.\{43\}$/s/\t/, /g;/^.\{44\}$/s/\r/./gp' input.file > new.file
```

I added a space after the comma to match the expected output. That's why the second match is for 44 rather than 43 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work for my situation. I upload a test file and you can make a test. Maybe there is sth incorrect with my problem description.

Comment: I suspect this is a UTF-8 problem, given your test sample. It does not appear that the spacing in the sample is a regular tab.

Comment: I tried to replace the tab with the same space in the command, but it didn't work.  Have you tried the same way on the test sample?